# how to implement escrow with paypal EURO currency in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I am new in PayPal escrow.
I am try to use escrow in my website.for seller and buyer like freelancer work.

so how to implement escrow in my codeigniter website?
using paypal and currency is EURO

Comment: you can refer this http://www.codexworld.com/paypal-payment-gateway-integration-in-codeigniter/

Comment: I want to milestone payment using paypal in euro currency.seller selling service(proofreading) and buyer applied.seller hire to buyer. hold payment by escrow after work done seller release payment

Comment: @WebGuru did you find any solution..?

Answer (score 0):

Check here for [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/) to fit your use case, the flow you would consider is "[Delayed Chained Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-delayedChainedPayment-curl-etc/)", to implement escrow and fund release once the service is delivered.

Comment: the Delayed Chained Payments can only holds the payment upto 90 days what if we want to hold the payment for more then 3 months lets say for 5 to 6 months..?

Answer (score 0):

PayPal does not support escrow.

Offering Escrow requires you to be licensed by the government which is a very complex process.

http://www.ArmorPayments.com is a licensed escrow service provider with APIs to integrate Escrow on your website. You can checkout the APIs @ http://www.armorpayments.com/api/pages/integrationGuide/